# ActiveRecord query with includes that avoids default scope on relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Conceptually I have 2 models, one with a default scope

```
class Model
  default_scope where: "is_acitve = 1"
end

class SpecialUser
   has_many :model

   ## 1
   def model
     Model.unscoped { super }
   end
end
```

I'm trying to have a few select places that override the default scope on Model - many other users of model exist, and they all should only see active Model's. Only a handful of special cases should have access to the inactive ones.

With method #1, I can handle this case

```
s = SpecialUser.find_by_id x
s.model  # <-- works for even is_active =0 cases.
```

But if I attempt something like below (for performance):

```
s = SpecialUser.includes(:model).where("id = 5")
```

the default scope is injected into the query.

Any way of avoiding the default scope even when using includes ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [unscoped](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped), which will remove the default_scope when querying:

```
s = SpecialUser.unscoped.includes(:model).where("id = 5")
```